# Completion of some $C[0,1]$ functions with some inner product is a reproducing kernel Hilbert space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, lp-spaces, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

**The problem**

Let $X$ be the space of $C^1[0,1]$ functions with the special property $f(0) = 0$. Consider the inner product defined in the following way:
$$\langle f, g \rangle = \int_0^1 f'(x) \overline{g'(x)} dx$$
I want to show that the space $H$ corresponding to the completion of $X$ under the induced norm metric is a reproducing kernel Hilbert space, i.e. $\forall x \in [0,1]$ that we have
$$|L_x(f)| = |f(x)| \leq C_x||f||_H, \forall f \in H$$
for some $C_x > 0$.

**My progress**

It is not particularly difficult to show that $L_x$ is bounded on the dense subspace $X$, as we can use the fundamental theorem of calculus effectively, i.e. for $f \in X$ we have
\begin{aligned}|L_x(f)| = |f(x)| = \Big | \int_0^x f'(y) dy \Big | \leq \int_0^x |f'(y)| dy \\ \leq \sqrt{\int_0^x 1^2dy}\sqrt{\int_0^x|f'(y)|^2dy} \leq \sqrt{x}||f'||_2 = \sqrt{x}||f||_H,  \end{aligned}

and so $C_x = \sqrt{x}$ suffices. My difficulty is enforcing this on the completion $X$.

In my mind, there seems to be two potential ways to approach this; we use that $X$ is a dense subspace (i.e. realize every $f \in H$ by some sequence $\{f_n\}_{n = 1}^\infty \subseteq X$ where $f_n \xrightarrow{H} f$) and either exploit some inequalities, or we attempt to say something meaningful about the limit $f$.

In particular, it would be nice if we could recover the fundamental theorem of calculus for the limit function $f$. This does not seem entirely unreasonable, as they are lots of known exercises regarding the limits of $C_1$ functions (in particular, that we can sometimes get uniform limits to be absolutely continuous functions, subject to some addition conditions, and so we still have FTC).

**My question**

Is there any result here I am missing which could tether this together? Or am I missing some sort of obvious forcing of limits? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This is a standard density argument, which is used for instance in Sobolev space theory.

1. The functional $L_x$ is continuous on the dense subspace. Hence, there is a unique extension to its closure, and this extension $L_x: X \to \mathbb R$ is linear and continuous. (In fact, this is true for every uniformly continuous function.)
2. The space $X$ is a closed subspace of the usual Sobolev space $H^1(0,1)$. Any function in $X \subset H^1(0,1)$ can be changed on a set of measure zero to obtain a continuous function (this is a Sobolev embedding theorem). For such functions, the extended functional $L_x$ indeed returns the evalution at $x$.

Comment: I appreciate the comment! Is there any (seemingly) simpler way to see that the limit should be equal to a continuous function a.e.? I have little exposure to Sobolev space theory so I'm not entirely sure how I would properly invoke the full result.

Comment: You are quite close already. Using your inequalities, you can prove $|L_x(f)| \le C \|f\|_H$. If $f\in X$  this means $\|f\|_\infty \le C \|f\|_H$. If $(f_n)$ is a Cauchy-Sequence in $X$ with respect to the $H$-norm, then it is a Cauchy sequence in the space of continuous functions. Now you have to show that the limit with respect to the $H$-norm and with respect to the sup-norm are equal.

Comment: Great, thank you!

Comment: I'm working out the rest of the argument and trying to show the limits are equal; presumably this would be done by showing convergence in the $H$-norm implies convergence in the sup-norm or vice-versa and applying uniqueness. However, I am having some trouble with this because the function $g$ for which we have $f_n \xrightarrow{\infty} g$ is not necessarily differentiable $\textit{a priori}$, so taking the $H$-norm doesn't necessarily make sense. We seemingly also don't known the limit in $H$, say $f$, is continuous $\textit{a priori}$, so taking its sup-norm may not make sense either.

Comment: That is, where the Sobolev space comes into play.